# Дочерний блок вылазит за блок родителя

Tags: css

Блок chat имеет ширину блока 46vh, а chat__mesage все равно вылазит за границы данного блока , как сделать так , чтобы chat__mesage не вылазил за рамки, а смог адаптироваться и пойти в низ?

```css
.chat {
  width: 46.2963vh;
  margin-left: 1.2963vh;
  margin-top: 1.48148vh;
}

.chat__allmesages {
  height: 35.83333vh;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.92593vh;
}

.chat__mesage {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 0.74074vh;
  padding: 0.37037vh 0.55556vh 0.37037vh 0.46296vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.38889vh;
  line-height: 1.94444vh;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0.46296vh;
}

.chat__msg {
  width: 46.2963vh;
  height: 2.77778vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 0.92593vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.38889vh;
  line-height: 1.66667vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 0.92593vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
         <ul class="chat__allmesages">
            <li class="chat__mesage">
               <p>Всем привет!</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
               <p>Всем ммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццц</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <input type="text" class="chat__msg">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте `max-width: 46.2963vh` и `word-wrap: break-word`

```css
.chat {
  width: 46.2963vh;
  margin-left: 1.2963vh;
  margin-top: 1.48148vh;
}

.chat__allmesages {
  height: 35.83333vh;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.92593vh;
}

.chat__mesage {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 0.74074vh;
  padding: 0.37037vh 0.55556vh 0.37037vh 0.46296vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.38889vh;
  line-height: 1.94444vh;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 46.2963vh; /*вот сюда добавлены новые свойства*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0.46296vh;
}

.chat__msg {
  width: 46.2963vh;
  height: 2.77778vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 0.92593vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.38889vh;
  line-height: 1.66667vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 0.92593vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
         <ul class="chat__allmesages">
            <li class="chat__mesage">
               <p>Всем привет!</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
               <p>Всем ммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммммццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццц</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <input type="text" class="chat__msg">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```